# Firebase: authorisation for edit / delete operations without creating an user login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created an app where anonymous users can write comments. Now I want them also to edit and delete (only) their comments. Is this possible without using firebase auth? 
Since it is only a one-time app for the user its kind of an overkill to create a login for each user.

I tried to store an editKey with the comment-object which should allow the user to edit / delete his comment. (I store this key for the user in a cookie in the browser)

[image]

Then somehow deny reading the editKey (`".read:" false`) via firebase rules. Only allow the write operation when the editKey is known: `".write": "data.val() == newData.val()"`

```
"comments" : {
    ".read": true,
    "$comment_id": {
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
            "text": {
                ".validate": "newData.isString()"
            },
            "created": {
                ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
            },
            "editKey": {
                ".read": false,
                ".write": "data.val() == newData.val()",
                ".validate": "newData.isString()"
            },
            "visible": {
                ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
            },
    }
}
```

But this does not work because the whole comment, which should be public, is not readable when I set the rule `".read:" false` for the editKey

Any ideas how this could be achieved **without** firebase.auth() ?

Comment: Have you seen [Firebase Auth anonymous auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)? That's basically exactly what you seem to be looking for -- a frictionless way to provide lightweight access control without requiring a login.

Comment: thanks Michael for the quick response, I have overseen this possibility, I will give it a try.

Comment: You could also save the editkey in a different location. Something like: `"keys" : { "$comment_id": _editKey_ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary
>   anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. These temporary
>   anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed
>   up to your app to work with data protected by security rules. If an
>   anonymous user decides to sign up to your app, you can link their
>   sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue
>   to work with their protected data in future sessions.